# Delete the block of the text in C

Tags: c, file, text, recording

Please help me to delete the block of text from text file using C program:
EXAMPLE:
CONTENT OF THE FILE:
INDEX: 1; NAME: name; SPEC: spec
NOTES: notes bla-bla-bla
-----
INDEX: 2; NAME: name; SPEC: spec
NOTES: notes bla-bla-bla
-----
INDEX: 3; NAME: name; SPEC: spec
NOTES: notes bla-bla-bla
-----

IN C PROGRAMM:
Enter the index: 2

THEN CONTENT OF THE FILE IS:
INDEX: 1; NAME: name; SPEC: spec
NOTES: notes bla-bla-bla
-----
INDEX: 3; NAME: name; SPEC: spec
NOTES: notes bla-bla-bla
-----

I think that algorithm is next: I read the content of file. Create a new file. If index is not I have entered, record the content from INDEX: n ... to -----  to another file. Then, when file ends, delete the first file and rename the second file into name of first. But i have no idea how to make it real

CODE I DONE:

```
    char *filename, *p, *index, *tmp, *q; //variables
    int id, number;
    filename = (char*)malloc((L_tmpnam + 1) * sizeof(char)); //
    p = (char*)malloc(L_tmpnam * sizeof(char));
    tmp = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    puts("Enter the index");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    tmpnam(filename);
    p = strstr(filename, "Temp\\"); p += 5;
    *(p + (strlen(p) - 2)) = '\0';
    strcat(p, ".txt");
    FILE *f, *f2; //for first and second files
    f = fopen("catalog.txt", "rt"); //opening for reading
    f2 = fopen(p, "wt"); //opening for writing
    while (fscanf(f, "INDEX: %d; NAME: %s; SPEC: %s", number, "name", "spec") != EOF) { //checking if index is that I need
        if (number == id) { //here has to be NOT recording the content
            while (strcmp(tmp, "-----") != 0) continue;
        }
        else { //Here has to be recording the content to another file
        }
    }
    fcloseall(); // closing all the files
```

Answer (score 1):

For writing in a file you can use functions such as fputs, fwrite, fprintf, depending of what you want to achieve and what kind of data you  have.